# Magento1 - How to migrate different table name using Data migration tool?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration, data-migration-tool

I have a table in `Magento1.9` named `monitoring` in `Magento2.0` this table is modified and the table name become `monitoring_base` with some of the table column  renamed, how can I map this table with modified `table` name and `column` name ?

```
monitoring            monitoring_base
----------            ---------------
id                    monitoring_id
status          =>    state
record_date           created_at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following dev doc: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/extend-the-tool.html

But in short, within your `map.xml` you want to

- Use a rename `document_rule` node to change the table name
- Add a move `field_rule` node to mape the fields

```
<source>
    <document_rules>
        <rename>
            <document>monitoring</document>
            <to>monitoring_base</to>
        </rename>
    </document_rules>
    <field_rules>
        <move>
            <field>monitoring.id</field>
            <to>monitoring_base.monitoring_id</to>
        </move>
        <move>
            <field>monitoring.status</field>
            <to>monitoring_base.state</to>
        </move>
        <move>
            <field>monitoring.record_date</field>
            <to>monitoring_base.created_at</to>
        </move>
    </field_rules>
</source>
```

Comment: Hi! With your answer, I'm getting the error `Document has ambiguous configuration: mageplaza_smtp_log` Any idea? I have defined the rules as you proposed, all inside `<source>`

Comment: Sorry, I think I found the error.